# BTYDplus: scheduled cores 1, 2, 8 did not deliver results, all values of the jobs will be affected

Tags: r, doparallel, mclapply

I'm using BTYDplus package functions.

Sometimes, quite randomly I would encounter this error below

```
Error in mcmc.list(lapply(draws, function(draw) draw$level_1[[i]])) :
  Arguments must be mcmc objects
In addition: Warning message:
In mclapply(1:chains, function(i) run_single_chain(i, cal.cbs, hyper_prior),  :
  scheduled cores 1, 2, 8 did not deliver results, all values of the jobs will be affected
```

What I've done so far to avoid having this issue is by keeping the MCMC small as bigger MCMC seems to correlate with higher likelihood of having failed cores.

Are there some best practices when it comes to running R in multi cores?

It's really frustrating because if when the job fails, I have to rerun the whole thing again and this takes a lot of time to monitor.